# npm does not work when trying to use ipywidgets in a virtual environment

Tags: node.js, npm, virtualenv, jupyter, display

I am using a python virtual environment on a server. Now i am trying to use ipywidgets and display. Here is my environment has:

[image]

It looks like I already have jupyter, nodejs and npm installed.

Then I install

[image]

Looks like fine.

Then I install:

[image]

Now I am trying to install:

[image]

you can see there is an error about npm.

The log info is:

```
Node v12.16.3

Yarn configuration loaded.
> /bin/npm pack @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager@2.0
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@jupyter-widgets%2fjupyterlab-manager failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/fefechen/.npm/_logs/2020-05-25T04_59_34_698Z-debug.log

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/scratch/feng/py36env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab/debuglog.py", line 47, in debug_logging
yield

  File "/scratch/feng/py36env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab/labextensions.py", line 93, in start
ans = self.run_task()

  File "/scratch/feng/py36env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab/labextensions.py", line 149, in run_task
for i, arg in enumerate(self.extra_args)
......
      File "/scratch/feng/py36env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab/labextensions.py", line 149, in <listcomp>
for i, arg in enumerate(self.extra_args)

  File "/scratch/feng/py36env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab/commands.py", line 388, in install_extension
return handler.install_extension(extension, pin=pin)

  File "/scratch/feng/py36env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab/commands.py", line 603, in install_extension
info = self._install_extension(extension, tempdir, pin=pin)

  File "/scratch/feng/py36env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab/commands.py", line 1499, in _install_extension
info = self._extract_package(extension, tempdir, pin=pin)

  File "/scratch/feng/py36env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab/commands.py", line 1578, in _extract_package
raise ValueError(msg % source)

ValueError: "@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager@2.0" is not a valid npm package

Exiting application: jupyter
```

So, how to deal with this issue: ValueError: "@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager@2.0" is not a valid npm package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because of firewall. i run the same code on my local computer, and it is good

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this and eventually gave up on conda, then pipenv and continued to have issues even after following the installation instructions to the letter in the computer's global environment; firewall on/off etc.

There are a lot of people apparently having this issue and unfortunately a lot of answers. I tried a bunch and through brute force found the following:

`jupyter lab paths`

... prints out where jupyter's environment is. When you cd into `C:\Users\<username>\.jupyter\lab` and run that same `jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager` install command, I got a lovely spinning backslash that twinkles for 30s and eventually returns an ambiguous message `Building jupyterlab assets (build:prod:minimize)`.

You can check to be sure this installed with: `jupyter labextension list`, which in my case spat out:

```
Known labextensions:
   app dir: c:\python38\share\jupyter\lab
        @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v2.0.0 enabled  ok
```

I apologize it's too late in the evening for me to continue fooling with with the virtual environment setup, but I hope this points in the right direction and saves others 3-4 hours of unproductive googling :-P